# sweetalert for delete alert in Laravel app

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, sweetalert

I'm trying to make a delete alert using `sweetalert` but whenever I confirm the `delete` from the sweetalert, first row of the table gets deleted always. Even if I try to delete, for example, the 3rd row from the table, sweetalert will delete the first row.

How can I correct my code?

```
<tbody>
        @foreach($album_names as $album)
        <tr>
          <td>{{ $album->album_name }}</td>
          <td>
             {!! Form::open(['route' => ['album.destroy',$album->id], 'method' => 'delete','id'=>'delete_form']) !!}
            <button class="btn btn-danger" id="delete">Delete</button>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                  $('button#delete').on('click', function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        swal({
                          title             : "Are you sure?",
                          text              : "You will not be able to recover this Album!",
                          type              : "warning",
                          showCancelButton  : true,
                          confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                          confirmButtonText : "Yes, delete it!",
                          cancelButtonText  : "No, Cancel delete!",
                          closeOnConfirm    : false,
                          closeOnCancel     : false
                        },
                  function(isConfirm){
                    if(isConfirm){
                      swal("Deleted!","your album has been deleted", "success");
                      setTimeout(function() {
                        $("#delete_form").submit();
                      }, 2000); // 1 second delay
                    }
                    else{
                      swal("cancelled","Your album is safe", "error");
                    }
                  }
            );});
            </script>
              {!! Form::close() !!}
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

Comment: `$("#delete_form").submit();` is what is deleting the form element, not sweetalert. That form function is most likely the culprit, and you have not provided the functional HTML or JS around that form.

Comment: Actually, the problem is that you're generating all of this within a loop. Each delete button has an ID of "#delete" and each form has an ID of "#delete_form", but there are many buttons and forms, each with the same ID. You aren't scoping your selector to know *which* form to actually submit. Switch your IDs to classes, and make sure to select the form based on which button was clicked.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're generating all of this within a loop. Each delete button has an ID of "#delete" and each form has an ID of "#delete_form", but there are many buttons and forms, each with the same ID.

You aren't scoping your selector to know which form to actually submit. Switch your IDs to classes, and make sure to select the form based on which button was clicked.

As an example, your code can be changed to something like this:

```
@foreach($album_names as $album)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $album->album_name }}</td>
      <td>
         {!! Form::open(['route' => ['album.destroy',$album->id], 'method' => 'delete','class'=>'delete_form']) !!}
        <button class="btn btn-danger delete-btn">Delete</button>
          {!! Form::close() !!}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('button.delete-btn').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var self = $(this);
        swal({
            title             : "Are you sure?",
            text              : "You will not be able to recover this Album!",
            type              : "warning",
            showCancelButton  : true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText : "Yes, delete it!",
            cancelButtonText  : "No, Cancel delete!",
            closeOnConfirm    : false,
            closeOnCancel     : false
        },
        function(isConfirm){
            if(isConfirm){
                swal("Deleted!","your album has been deleted", "success");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    self.parents(".delete_form").submit();
                }, 2000); //2 second delay (2000 milliseconds = 2 seconds)
            }
            else{
                  swal("cancelled","Your album is safe", "error");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is untested, but it should help get you started. Let me know if this helps.